# How to wrap up external api response in order to meet json datasource backend requirements

Tags: plugins, datasource, grafana

I’m trying to create a grafana datasource plugin which is to return a response with table type format.
There is a third party rest API which should provide data to the datasource, however, the request/response format of this external API do not conform with the example simple-json-datasource plugin urls and requests formats.
Is there a way I could wrap up the external api response in the datasource backend methods (/query) which is then called by the front-end part of datasource? (external api URL will be provided at the datasource settings UI while adding the datasource)
I'll appreciate the answers/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write code that transforms the third party API response into the table type format.

You may want to start off of something like this: https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource

Clone that project, and change the url values passed in options to the doRequest() function, those values should point to your third party API.

The doRequest() function seems to return a Promise, so you can do your data transformation when they are fulfilled, for example:

```
// simple-json-datasource/src/datasource.js 
// in the query() function
return this.doRequest(options).then(function(result) {
    // your transform code here;
    return transformedResult;
})
```